# Adding a class to tag list in a function

Tags: functions, taxonomy, tags

How can I add a class to the function so I can style the output tags as boxes in css?

```
<?php
    if(get_the_tag_list()) {
        echo get_the_tag_list('<ul><li>','</li><li>','</li></ul>');
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are passing the `before` parameter that you can simply add any class that you want. You then style that class in `style.css`.

```
<?php
    if ( get_the_tag_list() ) {
        echo get_the_tag_list('<ul class="tag-list"><li class="tag-item">','</li><li class="tag-item">','</li></ul>'); 
    }
?>
```

Comment: this applies a class of tag-item to one tag in the list. `<ul class="tag-list">

    <li class="tag-item">
        <a rel="tag" href="tag url"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a rel="tag" href="tag url"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a rel="tag" href="tag url"></a>
    </li>

</ul>`

Can it be applied to each tag?

Comment: Yes, see my edited answer. You just need to add `class="tag-item"` to the `$sep` parameter.